# Applying CSS by referencing an external hot linked image hosted on a different website

Tags: html, css

This is not a duplicate question because I am trying to override css of a external image with a href value.

I have this external image put all over a wordpress website but I cannot figure out a way to change image width with css. 
The problem is I cannot alter the code here.The "wpd_wrapper" class is used on other places on the website as well.

I want to make the image width 110px

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/nuh-strange-face-single/id392890270?at=11lSfu&amp;mt=1&amp;app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/images/badges/en-us/badge_music-lrg.svg) no-repeat;width:162px;height:40px;"></a>
</div>
```

I have tried selecting the image with [attribute] like below. But it is not working. What Am I doing wrong here?

```
img[url*="badge_music-lrg.svg"] {
    width: 110px !important;
}
```

Comment: You might be screwed there, everything I tried actually caused the background image to not load.

Comment: @VikingBlooded I added some code I used before. There I try to select the image by name using the attribute. However it is not working either.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work either
a[href$='badge_music-lrg.svg'] {
    width: 110px !important;
}

Comment: because you are targeting an image, it's not an image, it's a background-image.

Comment: @Quentin this is not a duplicate as he is asking a very specific question about targeting an element in a specific way. Not about precedence

Comment: try a[background$='badge_music-lrg.svg']

Comment: Thank you @VikingBlooded ! But does not work either. However I was able to fix it. I am going to add the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Quentin's directions and came up with the answer

```
a[style*='badge_music-lrg.svg'] {
width: 110px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an `<img>` so the `img` type selector won't match.

It doesn't have a `url` attribute, so your attribute selector which looks for `url=something` won't match.

Target something that is there. It is an `<a>` element and it has a `style` attribute.

Comment: Thank you Quentin and @VikingBlooded

Here I matched an a element with style attribute that has 'badge_music-lrg.svg' anywhere  in it.

Comment: a[style*='badge_music-lrg.svg'] {
    width: 110px !important;
}